# How to move multiple files over network from terminal

Tags: command-line, samba, gvfs

I am using this command

```
gvfs-move file smb://server/directory/file
```

to move files over a samba share I would like to transfer multiple files by piping the results of a gvfs-ls to the same command however I cannot use a wild card to limit the search like this

```
gvfs-ls smb://server/directory/*.mkv
```

How do I create a list of files over a samba share and proccess those?

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but why can't you glob?

Comment: @djeikyb when I am a good enough python programmer to know about glob I would probably do the whole thing in python but thanks for the comment. Interestingly I found it fairly difficult to find anything on file management in python but I am probably searching for the wrong thing

Comment: Oh, sorry.. globbing is any sort of pattern matching. You said * wasn't working for you, which puzzles me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would this work?

```
find . -iname *.mkv | xargs 'command'
```

Goodluck.

Comment: can you specify a samba folder to perform the find on?

Comment: @Allan you should be able to instead of the `.` use the samba folder location.

Comment: to find on a smb folder not mounted by fstab I had to write it like this find ~/.gvfs/"videos on media-centre"  -iname *.mkv I'll check out if the whole command works tomorrow dusty and give you an update.

Comment: the problem I'm having is a spaces problem because find needs the .gvfs/ folder name to search on which always has spaces in which get passed through to gvfs-move which cries :(

Comment: @Allan what you can do is to enter the the directory you want to copy from and run the command above I have listed. if you need a path with spaces `"pathhere"` that should solve that issue.

Comment: @dustyprogrammer managed to put a quick script together http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/567723/ working like a charm. Had to use a script because I want it to be done automatically thanks for the help

Comment: @dustyprogrammer,@Allan read `man find` and `man xargs`. Using `find`s `-print0` option, and the `-0` `xargs` option, you can easily handle spaces in filenames.  

`find ~/.gvfs/"videos on media-centre" -type f -iname '*.mkv' -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 -I {} gvfs-move {} /home/allan/Videos/Transfer/`